# I want to disable/ did not want to show "header" on specific page of my React app

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to hide/disable "header" on a specific page of my react app given below is the code for my components :

I want to hide header on "/dct" path

```
export default function (WrappedComponent,theme) {
  class Authentication extends PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { };
    }


    componentDidUpdate() {
      this.checkAuth();
    }

    checkAuth() {
      const { isLoggedIn, history: { push} } = this.props;
      if (!isLoggedIn) {
        push('/')
      }
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <Fragment>
     <article data-theme={theme}>
          {this.checkAuth()}
          <Header />
          <main>
            {this.props.isLoggedIn && <WrappedComponent />}
          </main>
          <Footer />
     </article>
        </Fragment>
      );
    }
  }

 const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
   return {
     isLoggedIn: state.login.loggedIn
   }
 } 
  return connect(mapStateToProps)(Authentication);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check your path name like this: `window.location.pathname !== "/dct"`

For example,

```
export default function (WrappedComponent,theme) {
  class Authentication extends PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { };
    }


    componentDidUpdate() {
      this.checkAuth();
    }

    checkAuth() {
      const { isLoggedIn, history: { push} } = this.props;
      if (!isLoggedIn) {
        push('/')
      }
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <Fragment>
     <article data-theme={theme}>
          {this.checkAuth()}
          {window.location.pathname !== "/dct && ( <Header /> )}
          <main>
            {this.props.isLoggedIn && <WrappedComponent />}
          </main>
          <Footer />
     </article>
        </Fragment>
      );
    }
  }

 const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
   return {
     isLoggedIn: state.login.loggedIn
   }
 } 
  return connect(mapStateToProps)(Authentication);
}
```

Let me know if this worked.

Comment: It worked and thanks to you now I know the logic behind this